# passing strongly typed list as parameter of generic function

Tags: c#, generics

```
List<Redemption> r = Redemption.Get();

public void Convert(List<T> list)
{

}
```

Say r contains a list of `Redemption` business objects, is there a way of using generics to pass that list into the generic function for processing? The reason I need generics is because it must be able to process list of other types such as members.

Comment: How do you attempt to call `Convert()`?

Comment: Yes. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ageis Could you please post the class definition in which `convert` is defined. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public void convert<T>(List<T> list)
{

}
```

This is now a generic method. For more information about this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

Comment: `<T>` is not a *must*. convert may be a member of a generic type like `class Temp<T>{ ... }`

Comment: @L.B. So that I have post in this case it should be wrong? I will ask the OP and I delete my post in this case. Thanks

Comment: This looks fine to me.  If it doesn't solve the problem it's because OP didn't put enough information in the question.

Comment: Thanks Christos I actually found the answer to my question on another post. But Thanks! I did actually try something similar but I wasn't aware you had to mark the method as generic as well.